# nginx vhost not serving static files

Tags: nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.site.dk;
  access_log /var/www/www.site.dk/logs/access.log;
  error_log /var/www/www.site.dk/logs/error.log;

  root /var/www/www.site.dk/;


  location / {

    index index.php index.html;

    if (-f $request_filename) {
      break;
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php last;
      break;
    }
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/www.site.dk$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get nginx to serve any physical file (css, images, js) without doing anything to it put let php handle all other requests. Everything that is not a physical file should be passed to php.

But it's not working, php is being executed, but calling a .css file is also passed to php as a request.

[Update]
I tried loading the css file directly in the browser www.site.dk/css/file.css.

Comment: how are you referencing your css in your html and also where is it located on the filesystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name www.site.dk; #Default is port 80
    root /var/www/www.site.dk/webroot; #Use a webroot!

    access_log /var/www/www.site.dk/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/www.site.dk/logs/error.log;

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri @use_php;
    }

    location @use_php {
            #The following line may have to be modified for desired behavior
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Some stuff from http://wiki.nginx.org/Drupal.